# Intellij: How can running single test but the path start from root project

Tags: pycharm

I am using Pycharm for coding Python. When I try to run a single test case. I see this log in terminal:

> Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest
>   test_calc_score.TestCalcScore.test_calc_score_success in
>   /Users/example/Documents/example_project/test/api/score

Because the running path is directly into test file, so some file path is wrong. I must update again file path. For example:

```
private_key_path = '../../../sample/example.txt' (back 3 folders)
```

But by doing this, when I run tests again for whole project, this path doesn't work anymore. So I must update again file path. i.e:

```
private_key_path = 'sample/example.txt'
```

So I think if we want to fix this, the location folder must be outside of test folderand start from root project. How can I do this in Intellij or Pycharm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the working directory inside a test run configuration. I believe it should fix the problem.

[image]